# thepiratebay3.org xpath's are not working, why?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I am trying to get selenium to click on a link for me but it cannot find any xpaths and I cannot figure out why

code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'/home/littlejiver/Downloads/chromedriver_linux64/chromedriver')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get("https://thepiratebay3.org/")
wait.until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="input-search"]'))).send_keys("Toy Story")
wait.until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="pirate-search"]'))).click()
wait.until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//div[@id="vpnModal"]//span[text()="No thanks"]'))).click()
wait.until(ec.element_to_be_clickable(
            (By.XPATH,
             '//*[@id="searchResult"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/div/a'))).click()
```

I've tried several differnet Xpaths and they are not being found and I cannot figure out why (the last link is the isssue in @id="searchResult")

any help would be appreciated

thanks,

littlejiver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<iframe target="_self" class="search-i" src="https://tpb.party/search/Toy+Story" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="100%" scrolling="auto" sandbox="allow-forms allow-same-origin allow-popups allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>\
```

Your element is under an iframe. Switch to it.

```
wait.until(ec.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CLASS_NAME, 'search-i')))
```

Complete Code

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get("https://thepiratebay3.org/")
wait.until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="input-search"]'))).send_keys("Toy Story")
wait.until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="pirate-search"]'))).click()
wait.until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//div[@id="vpnModal"]//span[text()="No thanks"]'))).click()
wait.until(ec.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CLASS_NAME, 'search-i')))
wait.until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="searchResult"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/div/a'))).click()
```

Comment: that worked perfectly! thanks so much, is the iframe a javascript thing? (I don't know javascript that well if you couldn't tell lol)

Comment: Selenium can only access the elements in a specific context, and the context of the main web page and the embedded iframe are different.